# Проблемка в Android SDK Studio после переделывания в apk

Tags: java, xml, android-sdk

В общем, я написал программу и при проверке эмулятором - она работает. В ней есть два Activity, с кнопками.Но когда я превратил программу в apk и запустил на телефоне, то она запускается, но в первом Activity, кнопки работают, а во втором Activity ничего не реагирует на касания(ни кнопки, ни ScrollView. В чём дело?

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_phone_book);

      scrLay = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.scrollLayout);
      btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
      btn3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
      btn4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
      btn5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button0);
      id = 1;
      dial = new Dialog(this);
      btn4.setAlpha(0);
      btn4.setClickable(false);

      dial.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);

      btn2 = (Button) dial.findViewById(R.id.button5);
      et1 = (EditText) dial.findViewById(R.id.editText);
      et2 = (EditText) dial.findViewById(R.id.editText2);

      btn2.setOnClickListener(this);
      btn1.setOnClickListener(this);
      btn3.setOnClickListener(this);
      btn4.setOnClickListener(this);
      btn5.setOnClickListener(this);


     ...



public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button0:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
            break;
        case R.id.button1:
            dial.show();
            break;
        case R.id.button5:
            name = (et1.getText().toString());
            number = (et2.getText().toString());
            dial.hide();

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams lParams = new 
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            lParams.topMargin = 20;
            lParams.leftMargin = 50;
            lParams.rightMargin = 50;

            LinearLayout llblank = new LinearLayout(this);
            llblank.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

            LinearLayout llblank1 = new LinearLayout(this);
            llblank1.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
            llblank1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rectangle);

            TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);
            tv1.setText(name);

            TextView tv2 = new TextView(this);
            tv2.setText(number);


            llblank.addView(tv1,lParams);

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams lParams1 = new 
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            lParams1.leftMargin = 50;
            lParams1.rightMargin = 50;
            lParams1.bottomMargin = 30;
            lParams1.topMargin = 30;

            llblank.addView(tv2,lParams);

            cb1 = new CheckBox(this);
            cb1.setAlpha(0);
            cb1.setId(id*10);

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams lParams2 = new 
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams(850,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            lParams2.bottomMargin = 30;

            llblank1.addView(llblank,lParams2);

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams lParams3 = new 
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            lParams3.topMargin = 39;

            llblank1.addView(cb1,lParams3);

            llblank1.setId(id);

            scrLay.addView(llblank1,lParams1);

            id = id + 1;
            break;
        case R.id.button4:
            i = 1;
            while (i<id) {
                CheckBox cbp = (CheckBox) findViewById(i*10);
                cbp.setAlpha(1);
                i++;
            }
            btn3.setAlpha(0);
            btn3.setClickable(false);
            btn1.setAlpha(0);
            btn1.setClickable(false);
            btn4.setAlpha(1);
            btn4.setClickable(true);
            break;
        case R.id.button2:
            i = 1;
            while (i<id) {
                CheckBox cbp = (CheckBox) findViewById(i*10);
                if (cbp.isChecked()) {
                    LinearLayout lm = (LinearLayout) findViewById(i*1);
                    lm.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                i++;
            }
            i = 1;
            while (i<id) {
                CheckBox cbp = (CheckBox) findViewById(i*10);
                cbp.setAlpha(0);
                i++;
            }
            btn3.setAlpha(1);
            btn3.setClickable(true);
            btn1.setAlpha(1);
            btn1.setClickable(true);
            btn4.setAlpha(0);
            btn4.setClickable(false);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Как здесь [задавать вопросы](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), чтобы получить полезный ответ.

Comment: добавьте ваш код